# Работа с базой данных в C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

Есть данные в БД, нужно в виде таблицы их вывести, как это сделать?

Подскажите, какой компонент брать для визуального вывода, и дайте ссылку где можно прочитать про базу данных в C#?

---

Работаю через wpf

Comment: [Работа с подключенным уровнем ADO .NET в C#](http://www.cyberforum.ru/ado-net/thread182279.html), это общием данные, на счёт WPF ничего конкретного не скажу

хотя я больше склонен использовать LINQ to SQL

Comment: Насколько я знаю, WPF работа с данными практически ничем не отличается. Разве что биндинги более гибкие. 

Я бы предложил еще поиграться с [тестовой базой в Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264901). Да и вообще почитать документацию к [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx)

Comment: Быстро работу с БД освоить вряд ли получится, но Вы можете попробовать почитать Троелсена, у него есть три главы, работы с БД через ADO.NET. [Язык программирования C# 2010 и платформа .NET 4 (Троелсен Э.)](http://padabum.com/d.php?id=347).

Answer (score 4):

Почитайте про EntityFramework Code First, Model First, Database First. Самым простым для освоения является Database First. Почитайте вот [Общая информация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/) , [Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20160705063043/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx). Остальное можно найти в гугле.
Для визуального вывода использовал DataGrid, биндил его на ObservableCollection.
Удачи.